# How to POST relational data with html form

Tags: html, post, related-content

I have a dynamic html form that creates with javascript new inputs for some products and each product has more colors.

```
<input type="text name="products[]">
<input type="text name="colors[]">
```

How do i create this html code so that when i have them in the post i could relate them with a for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do it like this:

```
<input type="text name="products[product_index][name]">
<input type="text name="products[product_index][colors][]">
```

or :

```
<input type="text name="products[product_index]">
<input type="text name="[colors][product_index][]">
```

Comment: <input type="text" name="products[0][name]">
        <input type="text" name="products[1][name]">
        <input type="text" name="products[0][colors][]">
        <input type="text" name="products[1][colors][]">
        <input type="text" name="products[1][colors][]">